# Heroku with container stack and ENTRYPOINT instruction continues to run with "/bin/sh -c"

Tags: heroku, containers, docker-entrypoint

I'll first preface with relevant sections in Heroku's documentation on their container registry and runtime for Docker deploys.

The [Docker commands and runtime](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/container-registry-and-runtime#dockerfile-commands-and-runtime) section states:

> - `ENTRYPOINT` is optional. If not set, `/bin/sh -c` will be used
>
>   - `CMD` will always be executed by a shell so that config vars are made
>       available to your process; to execute single binaries or use images
>       without a shell please use `ENTRYPOINT`

I want to highlight that last sentence (emphasis added):

> to execute **single binaries** or use images **without a shell** please use `ENTRYPOINT`

Furthermore, in the [Unsupported Dockerfile commands](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/container-registry-and-runtime#unsupported-dockerfile-commands) section.

> - `SHELL` - The default shell for Docker images is `/bin/sh`, you can override
>     with `ENTRYPOINT` if necessary.

My understanding from this is that if the `ENTRYPOINT` instruction exists in my Dockerfile, then Heroku's container stack will **not** execute the command with `/bin/sh`. But apparently my understanding is wrong, because that seems to be still happening.

Here is an illustration of what my Dockerfile looks like:

```
FROM golang:1.14 as build

# ... builds the binary

FROM scratch

# ... other irrelevant stuff

COPY --from=build /myprogram /myprogram

ENTRYPOINT ["/myprogram"]
```

The final image contains the binary at `/myprogram` in a `scratch` base image. Since `scratch` doesn't have `/bin/sh`, it is necessary to override this. According to their documentation, this is done with `ENTRYPOINT`.

However, when I deploy it to Heroku, it appears to still execute with a shell. To illustrate:

```
% heroku ps -a my-app-name
== web (Free): /bin/sh -c --myflag1 --myflag2 (1)
```

Which means it's ultimately executing:

```
/myprogram /bin/sh -c --myflag1 --myflag2
```

Which is obviously not what I want. But what happened to this part of the documentation (which I highlighted earlier)?:

> to execute single binaries or use images without a shell please use `ENTRYPOINT`

...

The heroku.yml file looks like the following:

```yaml
---
build:
  docker:
    web: Dockerfile

run:
  web:
    command:
    - --myflag1
    - --myflag2
```

I still have the same problem with the shell form and the exec form. Meaning, I also tried with the heroku.yml file looking like this:

```yaml
---
build:
  docker:
    web: Dockerfile

run:
  web: --myflag1 --myflag2
```

Now, I know that I can get everything to "just work" by basing the final image on an image that has `/bin/sh` and remove the `ENTRYPOINT` instruction, specifying the command with `/myprogram`. I don't *need* to use scratch, but I *want* to, and **should** be able to use `scratch`, right? It's what I've been using for many years to run my statically linked binaries in containers and I have never come across problems like this when deploying on other platforms.

So am I misunderstanding their documentation? What do I need to do to get rid of this `/bin/sh` shenanigan?

Comment: The `heroku.yml` `run` is overwriting your entrypoint.

Comment: @TinNguyen I'm pretty sure that's not the case because the error message from my program (which I didn't include in my post) complains about `-c` (from the problematic  `/bin/sh -c`) being an unrecognized flag. Which is actually a correct behavior. Can you point to any part of Heroku's documentation that says `run` is overwriting `ENTRYPOINT`?

Comment: I'm also running into this issue, did you find a solution?

Comment: @ileitch Unfortunately, I haven't found a solution yet. I've gone back to deploying to a tried-and-true k8s cluster with Helm where trivial things like this are just not a problem.

Comment: I would try two separate things. First, add the `--myflag1` and `--myflag2` parameters to the ENTRYPOINT in your Dockerfile. If that won't work, it seems to me that Heroku is compelled to add the `/bin/sh` as a CMD instruction for some reason. Maybe if you specify a CMD yourself, it won't do it?

Comment: @James did you ever find a solution to this?